# How to avoid downcasting in composite pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, composite, visitor-pattern

I use a composite pattern to represent a [mechanical network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_network), which describes the mechanical behavior of a material, see e.g. the [Maxwell-Wiechert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Maxwell_model) model, a spring in parallel with n [Maxwell Elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_material). **A maxwell element iteslf is a spring in series with a damper**.
The mechanical network is composed dynamically at runtime. To this end, I have derived `Spring`, `MaxwellElement`, and `ParallelConnection` from a common base class `Component`:

```
struct Component {
    virtual void add_component (Component* ) { }
    virtual Tensor<2> stress (const Tensor<2> &strain) const = 0;
    virtual ~Component () = default;
};

struct Spring : Component {    
    Tensor<2> stress (const Tensor<2> &strain) const override {return {};};
};

struct SpecialSpring : Spring {

    Tensor<1> principal_stresses (const Tensor<1> &strain_eigenvalues) const {return {};};
};

struct ParallelConnection : Component {

    void add_component (Component* c) override {components.emplace_back(c);}
    Tensor<2> stress (const Tensor<2> &strain) const override {
        Tensor<2> s; 
        for (const auto& c : components)
            s += c->stress(strain);
        return s;
    };
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>> components;
};

struct MaxwellElement : Component {

    Tensor<2> stress (const Tensor<2> &strain) const override {
        auto special_spring = dynamic_cast<SpecialSpring*>(spring.get());
        if (special_spring) {
            const auto ps = special_spring->principal_stresses (eigenvalues(strain));
            // Some cheap calculations using ps and member variables
            // of MaxwellElement, which are left out for simplicity.
            return {}; // <- meaningful result
        } else {      
            const auto s = spring->stress (strain);
            // Some expensive calculations using s and member variables
            // of MaxwellElement, which are left out for simplicity.
            return {}; // <- meaningful result
        }   
    };    

    virtual void add_component (Component* c) {
        if (!spring)
            spring.reset(dynamic_cast<Spring*>(c));
        assert (spring);
    }

    std::unique_ptr<Spring> spring;
};
```

The goal is to compute the stress response of a material, represented by the network, for a given strain tensor (both are symmetric). Under certain assumptions, the computation within `MaxwellElement::stress(const Tensor<2>&)` can be significantly sped up by using the principal stresses, i.e. the eigenvalues of the stress tensor (and the corresponding eigenvectors, which has been neglected for simplicity, see this [paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-T-H-E-O-R-Y-OF-FINITE-VISCOELASTICITY-A-N-D-N-U-M-Reese-Govindjee/3df47434afb5440ab39fb02de062c0d3425d0067) if you are interested in the theory). Lets assume that `SpecialSpring` fulfills these assumptions, but in general, `Spring` doesn't.

[live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/e5q6nr1e5) of current implementation.

What really bothers me with my current implementation, is that I have to manually downcast to `SpecialSpring` in order to access `SpecialSpring::principal_stresses(const Tensor<1> &)`. Of course, I could add a virtual function `Component::get_type()` to check whether I am dealing with a `SpecialSpring`, but I haven't done this here to keep the code short.

Now, I am thinking about using a Visitor like this

```
struct SpringVisitor : ComponentVisitor {

void visit (const Spring* s) {
    result = s->stress (strain);
}
void visit (const SpecialSpring* s) {
    result = s->principal_stresses (eigenvalues(strain));
}

Tensor<2> strain;
std::variant<Tensor<1>, Tensor<2>> result;
}
```

Implementing the `ComponentVisitor` and adding the `accept` methods are left as homework ;) I hope it is still clear what I am aiming for. Now, based on `std::variant::index()`, I can choose the correct algorithm. However, I still fells like a bad design.

**Is there any better way to achieve what I have described above?**

**Is my current implementation the problem itself and I am dealing with sort of an XY problem?**

Comment: Sounds a bit like the problem which [multimethods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) would solve. They've been proposed for C++ long ago, but never made it into the language. Looks like pattern matching will provide something similar, but with different properties.

Comment: @dyp Yes, you're right. Multimethods would be nice to have in this particular case. I haven't heard about pattern matching. Is [this](https://medium.com/software-design/pattern-matching-in-c-14-79f4409c1228) what you are referring to.

Comment: Yes, in a way. Or something like [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1371r1.pdf). The idea would be to define a pattern of the two types involved (which class derived from Component and which Spring type). Both multimethods and pattern matching don't fit exactly to your problem, because in your case the spring is hidden inside the Component and not accessible to the caller of `Component::stress` to dispatch over.

Comment: In general, you can push the implementation ("cheap calculations" and "expensive calculations" from MaxwellElement) into the Spring class. There would be two virtual functions which usually do the same thing, but SpecialSpring overrides one for the "cheap calculations" case. This of course ties SpecialString and MaxwellElement...

Comment: Visitor is indeed a standard solution for traversing Composites; however, I think the example here is incomplete. Somehow, the `SpringVisitor` must be passed into the `Component`, i.e. you seem to be missing the `accept()` method from the Visitor pattern.

Comment: @dyp Unfortunately, pushing the implementation into `Spring` isn't an option here, as I need parameters of `MaxwellElement` class for the calculation, like the damper viscosity.  I haven't made this clear enough above. My apologies. I'll make an edit.

Comment: @jaco0646 You are absolutely right, I have to add an accept method. I just wanted to point an issue I'd have when using a visitor. I'll update my question to point this out.

Comment: Pushing the implementation can always be achieved, but it suffers from tight coupling. E.g. in the Spring class, `Tensor<2> stress (const Tensor<2> &strain) const override; virtual Tensor<2> stress_optimized_for_maxwell(/*whatever parameters are necessary*/) = 0;` The `stress_optimized_for_maxwell` should be able to operate both on ordinary and special strings, but uses the cheap computation on special strings.

Comment: @dyp You are right, thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, it seems that one way or another, you need to programmatically determine what calculations to perform - either the cheap ones or the expensive ones - and the question is just how to approach this.

Assuming that `Tensor<1>` is just a structurally simplified representation of `Tensor<2>` (because tensors, in general, are like that, right?) I would go with the idea of overriding the `stress()` also in the `SpecialSpring` class:

- it would call `eigenvalues(strain)` internally,
- it would generalize its internal calculation result into `Tensor<2>` representation and return that.

Something like this:

```
struct Spring : Component {    
    virtual Tensor<2> stress (const Tensor<2> &strain) const override {return {};};
};

struct SpecialSpring : Spring {
    Tensor<1> principal_stresses (const Tensor<1> &strain_eigenvalues) const {return {};};

    virtual Tensor<2> stress (const Tensor<2> &strain) const override {
        Tensor<1> t1 = principal_stress(eigenvalues(strain));
        Tensor<2> t2 = some_function_to_generalize_T1_to_T2(t1);
        return t2;
    };
};
```

Then, inside `MaxwellElement::stress()` you just call `spring->stress(strain)` and then you check whether the returned `Tensor<2>` is simple enough to do the cheap calculations.

Of course, with such approach, there's a new question - are the extra calculations (changing the representation of `Tensor<1>` to `Tensor<2>` and then basically doing the reverse thing after `Tensor<2>` is returned) better (performance-wise) than a `dynamic_cast<>`?

Comment: +1 as this approach might be helpful for others. However, this does not work in my case. A first-order tensor `Tensor<1>` is a vector, and a second-order tensor `Tensor<2>` is a matrix. That is, `Tensor<1>` can be stored in a `Tensor<2>`. The problem with your solution is that the original result of `stress(...) ` would be lost.  When a `SpecialSpring` is one of the components in `ParallelConnection`, it needs to call the original `stress(...)` function.

Comment: What bothers me with my current approach is not so much the performance penalty of the `dynamic_cast<>` (even the cheap calculation is much more expensive than that) it is more the fact that I have downcast at all. To me this is a sign of poor design choices of my code. Therefore, the visitor-pattern attemplt. Maybe having `MaxwellElement` and `SpecialMaxwellElement`, would be a solution. But thanks, I really appreciate your help.